# ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre C# y C# en .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas soy nuevo en esto, he estado estudiando java y me gustaría estudiar ahora C# que he leido que con el puedes desarrollar juegos y hacer aplicaciones de escritorio, pero mi duda es, Si estudio c# en .net es igual al c# normal? o existe alguna diferencia?

Gracias.

Comment: C# es el lenguaje, y .NET (Runtime) es el ambiente de ejecución (+ una colección de librerías).  Es similar a decir que Java es el lenguaje y el JVM es el ambiente de ejecución. C# en .NET es el C# normal y el único C# que existe.

Comment: te refieres .net(estándar) y .net core?

Comment: @JesseR.Jose no se exactamente amigo, me refiero a si c# es un lenguaje y se programa exclusivamente en .net o si por el contrario se puede programar sin este framework y si varía mucho. gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# es el lenguaje de programación. Mientras que .NET Framework es el conjunto de librerias escrita en mayormente C#.

Por ejemplo [`System.IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) es una librería que pertenece al .NET Framework al igual que la clase `File`, ahora bien, la clase fue escrita en C#.

La razón por la que existe en .NET Framework es para simplificanos tareas que  serian muy tediosas y complicadas principalmente para los principiantes. Por ejemplo cuando quieres escribir un texto en un archivo se utiliza:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("ruta.txt", "Hola mundo");
```

Simple, verdad? Esto es todo lo que el framework hace por ti:

```
public static void WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    if (path.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyPath"));
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    InternalWriteAllText(path, contents, StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM, true);
}

[System.Security.SecurityCritical]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
[ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
private static void InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, bool checkHost)
{
    Contract.Requires(path != null);
    Contract.Requires(encoding != null);
    Contract.Requires(path.Length > 0);

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding, StreamWriter.DefaultBufferSize, checkHost))
        sw.Write(contents);
}
```

Y en este ejemplo no incluimos la implementacion del `StreamWriter` que maneja codigo mas complicado. Aqui el metodo [`Write`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,715bd5de78456219) del [`StreamWriter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs):

```
public override void Write(String value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {

#if FEATURE_ASYNC_IO
                CheckAsyncTaskInProgress();
#endif

                int count = value.Length;
                int index = 0;
                while (count > 0) {
                    if (charPos == charLen) Flush(false, false);
                    int n = charLen - charPos;
                    if (n > count) n = count;
                    Contract.Assert(n > 0, "StreamWriter::Write(String) isn't making progress!  This is most likely a race condition in user code.");
                    value.CopyTo(index, charBuffer, charPos, n);
                    charPos += n;
                    index += n;
                    count -= n;
                }
                if (autoFlush) Flush(true, false);
            }
        }
```

Y todo eso se resume en el primer ejemplo.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es correctísima y muy interesante, no se si es aplicable a este caso. El OP pregunta la diferencia entre C# y C# en .Net(sea lo que sea eso), no la diferencia entre el lenguaje y el framework. Personalmente, yo habría esperado a que aclarara exactamente cual era su duda :)

Comment: Pense eso tambien pero muchas veces he leido articulos donde dicen  'Aprende C# .NET en 3 meses' y cuando eres un principiante cosas como esas pueden confundir mucho. De ahi que decidi escribir esta respuesta.

Comment: No lo veas como un reproche, y ya te digo que me parece una buena respuesta. Solo quería decir que yo habría esperado un poco a que el OP aclarara la pregunta. De hecho tiene dos comentarios a los que no ha respondido.

Comment: @Einer Gracias por las respuesta, muy buena. Yo me refiero a si al igual que visual basic, varia mucho la estructura al programar con .net o sin hacerlo. gracias !

Comment: @jlgf estas confundiendo vb 6 con vb.net??? son dos lenguajes distintos...